# How to merge new data to old array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a array like this. Here I have included only 5 fields but in real I have around 45 fieldname.

```
0: {id:1, product_name: 'aaa', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4}
1: {id:2, product_name: 'bbb', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4}
2: {id:3, product_name: 'ccc', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4}
3: {id:4, product_name: 'ddd', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4}
```

I want to get the sum of val1, val2 and val3 and display in total column and append '%' sign to this 3 value too.

I did following to get the sum and append %

```
temp = temp.map((row) => {
    const newRow= {};
    let total = 0;

    total = row['val1'] +
            row['val2'] +
            row['val3'] +

    newRow['total'] = total;

    newRow['val1'] = row['val1'] + '%';
    newRow['val2'] = row['val2'] + '%';
    newRow['val3']   = row['val3'] + '%';

    return newRow;
});
```

With this code I return only val1, val2 and val3 in my array. How can I append other 42 columns and get the final result.

Comment: You can use `reduce()`.

Comment: @CodeManiac can you show me?

Comment: @how the product name output looks line ? is it in array or string concatenated

Comment: @codemaniac its an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like that

```js
var temp = [{id:1, product_name: 'aaa', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4},
{id:2, product_name: 'bbb', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4},
{id:3, product_name: 'ccc', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4},
{id:4, product_name: 'ddd', val1:1, val2:2, val3:4}];

temp = temp.map(row => {
  const newRow = row;
  let total = 0;

  total = parseInt(row['val1']) +
    parseInt(row['val2']) +
    parseInt(row['val3']);

  newRow['total'] = total;

  newRow['val1'] = row['val1'] + '%';
  newRow['val2'] = row['val2'] + '%';
  newRow['val3'] = row['val3'] + '%';

  return newRow;
});
$("#result").append(JSON.stringify(temp) + "<br />");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='result'>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take an array of the wanted keys and map new properties for a single array.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, product_name: 'aaa', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }, { id: 2, product_name: 'bbb', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }, { id: 3, product_name: 'ccc', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }, { id: 4, product_name: 'ddd', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }],
    keys = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    result = data.map(o => Object.assign(...keys.map(
        (t => k => ({ total: t += o[k], [k]: o[k] + '%' }))
        (0)
    )));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With rest for objects.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, product_name: 'aaa', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }, { id: 2, product_name: 'bbb', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }, { id: 3, product_name: 'ccc', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }, { id: 4, product_name: 'ddd', val1: 1, val2: 2, val3: 4 }],
    result = data.map(({ id, product_name, ...o, total = 0 }) => Object.assign(
        { id, product_name },
        ...Object.entries(o).map(([k, v]) => (total += v, { [k]: v + '%' })),
        { total }
    ));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: later I need to show id and product_name too in above case.

Comment: `Object.assign({},o,...keys.map` would have the original props included without mutating the original.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your definition of const newRow to such:

```
let temp = this.some.map((row) => {
  const newRow = {...row};
  let total = 0;
  total = row['val1'] +
          row['val2'] +
          row['val3'];
  newRow['total'] = total;

  newRow['val1'] = row['val1'] + '%';
  newRow['val2'] = row['val2'] + '%';
  newRow['val3'] = row['val3'] + '%';

  return newRow;
});
```